# Executing Multiple sql files in a single sql file

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have two sql files .
file 1 is

```
create table emp (emp_id int , emp_name text,dept_id int)
create table dept (dept_id int , dept_name text)
```

file 2

```
insert into emp (1,'Mike',100)
insert into emp (2,'Dave',200)
insert into dept (100,'sales')
insert into dept (200,'Marketing')
```

I want to run two sql files in a single script. I am using psql tool in pgadmin not shell . Could you please help me . i can do it in oracle but i am new to postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you mean by "psql tool in pgadmin" - those are two separate tools. If you mean "psql" then...

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

There are two "include" backslash commands. If you do

```
\i path/to/script.sql
```

the path is relative to the *current directory* where you run psql.

If you do

```
\ir path/to/script.sql
```

the path is relative to the *script doing the including* (which is more useful imho).

If you use absolute paths then there is no difference between the two.

NOTE: only the outer-most script should have BEGIN ... COMMIT - you can't nest the transactions.

Comment: Hi , I tried . In mac it works but in Windows it throws syntax error at \i . My code is begin \i 'C:\\documents\file1.sql' ; \i ' C:\\documents\file2.sql ; end ; this code works fine in mac but not in windows

Comment: If `\dt` works to list tables then it isn't the command and must be the paths. If thst is so try forward slashes: `C:/documents/file1.sql`.

Comment: Hi Richard , Thanks a lot for your answer . It worked . Thanks once again